# Add Repository In Debian 6.0.8

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt, repository, ppa

I am trying to add a repository in Debian 6.0.8

```
sudo cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.8

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kakrueger/openstreetmap
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Is any other alternative to install software from that repository?